# Avoiding a double 'for' loop in function

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
v <- function(r){
    for(i in 2:length(df$v1)){
    df$v1[i] <- 1/((1+r)^(i-1))
  }
    for(i in 3:length(df$v2)){
    df$v2[i] <- 1/((1+r)^(i-2))
  }
  df
}
```

When I run the function (i=.25) for a predefined data.frame 'df' with two columns of length 9 (v1 and v2) I obtain the desired output:

```
        v1        v2 
1  0.0000000 0.0000000
2  0.8000000 0.0000000
3  0.6400000 0.8000000
4  0.5120000 0.6400000
5  0.4096000 0.5120000
6  0.3276800 0.4096000
7  0.2621440 0.3276800
8  0.2097152 0.2621440 
9  0.1677722 0.2097152
```

I need to run this function for a data.frame with far more columns.  I can envision creating a for loop in this example:

```
for(k in 2:3){
  for(i in k:length(df[1]) etc...
 }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there may be a faster way to combine the statements in the original v function so that neither two separate 'for' statements nor a double 'for' loop is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `v2` in terms of `v1` to prevent doing the calculations twice. Just change the second for loop in your function with the following.

```
df$v2 <- c(0, df$v1[1:(nrow(df)-1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can just use `sapply`</s> without using any loop:

```
my.fct.1 <- function(x,r){return(1/(1+r)^(x-1))}
df$v1 <- my.fct.1(1:length(df$v1), r)
```

Then similarly for `df$v2`:

```
my.fct.2 <- function(x,r){return(1/(1+r)^(x-2))}
df$v2 <- my.fct.2(1:length(df$v2), r)
```

---

**Edit**

If you have many columns, you might want to consider the following

```
my.fct <- function(x,k,r){return(1/(1+r)^(x-k))}
df <- t(sapply(X = 1:dim(df)[1], FUN = my.fct, k = 1:dim(df)[2], r = r))
```

Comment: There isn't a need for sapply as the function is vectorized just fine.